# Trying to get column value to only return the column it references to it in the same table in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

The values in `AnswerInt` is a number 1 through 5. The number goes with the column `LabelText` number.

I want to get the column `AnswerInt` to return and then only the column `LabelText` it references.

```
SELECT
    Question,
    AnswerInt,
    AnswerText,
    CreatedTime,
    LabelText1,
    LabelText2,
    LabelText3,
    LabelText4,
    LabelText5,
    SurveyType,
    ResponseTypeDesc,

FROM
    dbo.WEBSITE_SURVEYS

WHERE
    CASE AnswerInt 
        WHEN '1' THEN 'LabelText1'
        WHEN '2' THEN 'LabelText2'
        WHEN '3' THEN 'LabelText3'
        WHEN '4' THEN 'LabelText4'
        WHEN '5' THEN 'LabelText5'
```

Answer (score 1):

As you have a number to define the value returned, which relates to the column, you could use [`CHOOSE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-choose-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) here; which is effectively a shorthand `CASE` expression:

```sql
SELECT Question,
       AnswerInt,
       AnswerText,
       CreatedTime,
       SurveyType,
       ResponseTypeDesc,
       CHOOSE(AnswerInt, LabelText1, LabelText2, LabelText3, LabelText4, LabelText5) AS LabelText
FROM dbo.WEBSITE_SURVEYS;
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean to put the `CASE` expression in the `SELECT` clause?

```sql
SELECT
    Question,
    AnswerInt,
    AnswerText,
    CreatedTime,
    SurveyType,
    ResponseTypeDesc,
    CASE AnswerInt
        WHEN '1' THEN LabelText1
        WHEN '2' THEN LabelText2
        WHEN '3' THEN LabelText3
        WHEN '4' THEN LabelText4
        WHEN '5' THEN LabelText5
    END AS LabelText

FROM
    dbo.WEBSITE_SURVEYS
```

Comment: Yes, but Im new at this and googled it.  Is that wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If the number in AnswerInt column goes with the column LabelText number then try this simple query:

```
select 
    Question,
    AnswerInt,
    AnswerText,
    CreatedTime,
    SurveyType,
    ResponseTypeDesc,
    CONCAT('LabelText', AnswerInt)LabelText
FROM
    dbo.WEBSITE_SURVEYS
```